# Multiple Plus/Minus boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using - and + buttons to decrease and increase the number of the text box, where I am having problems is when I use multiple counters on one page

This is the script for one. How can I edit this code so I can use it as many times as i wish on on one page

```
<script language=javascript>
function process(v){
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
value+=v;
document.getElementById('v').value = value;
}
</script>

<input type=button value='-' onclick='javascript:process(-1)'>
<input type=test size=10 id='v' name='v' value='0'>
<input type=button value='+' onclick='javascript:process(1)'>
```

Comment: Use a class for the input type , and use that class in jquery/javascript to create the elements dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is tagged with jQuery, here's a jQuery answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/pxJHc/

```
<div>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='minus' />
    <input type='text' size='10' class='value' value='0' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='plus' />
</div>
```

---

```
$('.minus, .plus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $input = $(this).siblings('.value');
    var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    $input.val(val + ($(this).hasClass('minus') ? -1 : 1));
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I was having the same issue. would you please guide me how can I limit the minimum value to 1?

Comment: @JunaidRehman Try `$input.val(Math.max(val + ($(this).hasClass('minus') ? -1 : 1), 1);`

Answer (score 0):

very easy :)

```
<script language=javascript>
function process(v, target){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(target).value);
    value+=v;
    document.getElementById(target).value = value;
}
</script>

<input type=button value='-' onclick='javascript:process(-1, "v")'>
<input type=test size=10 id='v' name='v' value='0'>
<input type=button value='+' onclick='javascript:process(1, "v")'>

<br />    

<input type=button value='-' onclick='javascript:process(-1, "v2")'>
<input type=test size=10 id='v2' name='v' value='0'>
<input type=button value='+' onclick='javascript:process(1, "v2")'>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, only issue is it keeps updating the first box and not the box that is assigned for that - and +

Comment: don't forget to change second input id >>> id='v2'